# Fading Effect for segmented line (QGraphicsLineItem)

Tags: python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I am drawing using QgraphicsLineItem such that after reaching certain length, it should give me fading effect for the line. So, the basic way I had used is appending its objects to a list and later setting its opacity which would give a fading type of effect. But the problem I am facing here is it is disappearing, but the points which connect a line gets overlapped.

[image: Segmented Line Image]

Below is the code Snippet:

```
   # Inherited Plotwidget class 
 
   def drawLine1(self,x,y,z):
            # Here x,y are coordinates and z if force for finger 1
            item = pg.QtWidgets.QGraphicsLineItem()
            item.setPen(pg.mkPen(width= z+ ModeOne.pen_wid_1, color = ModeOne.color_1))
            # For drawing one point

               if x[-2] == x [-1]:
                    x[-2] = x[-1] - 1
                    y[-2] = y[-1] - 1

               item.setLine(x[-2],y[-2],x[-1],y[-1])

  
        self.addItem(item)
        self.rectdata_fir.append(item)
    self.disappear_item(self.rectdata_fir)

    def disappear_item(self, item_list):
        if len(item_list)>50:
            item_list[10].setOpacity(0.10)
            item_list[9].setOpacity(0.09)
            item_list[8].setOpacity(0.08)
            item_list[7].setOpacity(0.07)
            item_list[6].setOpacity(0.07)
            item_list[5].setOpacity(0.05)
            item_list[4].setOpacity(0.04)
            item_list[3].setOpacity(0.03)
            item_list[2].setOpacity(0.02)
            item_list[1].setOpacity(0.01)
            self.removeItem(item_list.pop(0))
```

So, initially have tried grouping that items into QGraphicsItemGroup and then set its opacity effect to 0.1. Alternatively, I had tried to set GraphicsEffect as opacity effect for each item.

Comment: None of your solution would work fine, because the problem comes from the fact that you're using individual items that are painted at different steps one above the other, so you end up with *blended* alpha values of the extruding [*caps*](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpen.html#capStyle) of each item's [`pen()`](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicslineitem.html#pen). Even using the `FlatCap` wouldn't work properly, because as soon as the angle between two different lines is greater than 5-10 degrees you'll end up with a similar effect caused by the line width. This would be possible if the paths were predictable »

Comment: » because it would then be possible to use a proper QGradient used as a QPen's own brush, but since it seems that you're actually drawing paths from finger movements, it would be almost impossible to do this under certain conditions (for instance, if the path intersects itself).